# Why do the buttons in my window look old in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, button, styles

I just began creating a new windows application in C++, using VS 2012, and instead of using the pre-made template for "win32 application", I simply started a blank project and wrote my window from scratch.

The problem is, the buttons look like this:

[image]

Then I realized I needed to embed a manifest, which was no issue, so I put this inside the code:

```
pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Afterward, to my displeasure, the button became this equally unattractive little guy:

[image]

For some reason, it's not looking how it is supposed to. Does anybody have any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: You can try setting the font using WM_SETFONT

Comment: How did you manage to install VS2012 on Windows 98 SE? :)

Comment: You have actually been specially selected to test drive Windows™' newest UI for Windows™ Gray™, our next-gen™, highly advanced™, future OS™. Please bear with us.

Comment: Is setting the font the only option? It seems a bit redundant =P

Comment: Rather than leaving us guessing, can you provide a screenshot of how you expect the button *should* look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Postmessage and WS_BORDER

Issue might be that you use WinAPI directly.
Have you tried sending `WS_BORDER` with PostMessage to the Control and set it 0 ?

Comment: Indeed! That was my mistake. I defined the button with WS_BORDER, which gave it that unattractive border. But the button still has unappealing text, as seen here: http://imgur.com/iq7iYW0

Comment: How it's unappealing ? Is it the font or padding of the button ?

Comment: Just the font, but I guess I'll have to change that via WM_SETFONT. Thanks for your help=)

Answer (score 1):

Link your manfifest to your application which specifies v6 common controls.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx